# why are form ids being displayed above forms?

Tags: forms

I have taken over some work and have not got much documentation on what has been done. I have turned off error message reporting in the Development module but this does not turn off the form id being displayed.

What I've been seeing is messages like this... `Form ID is : search_block_form` on every page with a form. They are green, rather than the usual red of an error message.

Comment: Are you using custom modules? Looks like leftover from `hook_form_alter()` development.

Comment: Looks like my comment and your answer was posted in exactly same second.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localised in nature and will not help future visitors

Comment: I think the point is that the question has too specific a scenario to help the Drupal answer community in general. I've edited it if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, never mind - always find the answer as soon as I've posted a question!

This is what I'd done...

```
function My_Module_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {

    drupal_set_message("Form ID is : " . $form_id);

    ...
```